# Time Machine says "Waiting for Backup" and never starting

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

In System Settings, Time Machine tells me, that it waits for the backup to complete (not the first backup). I formatted the partition in my external hard drive as well. I also called

```
sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/502 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd.plist
```

since `backupd` was nowhere to be found in `htop`. This returned an error message of `Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error`.

Digging a little deeper, I stumbled upon the errors in my Console.app:

```
TimeMachineSettings activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.backupd.session.xpc

backupd Backup failed: BACKUP_IN_PROGRESS_REQUEST_DROPPED (46) Elapsed time: Calculating...

TimeMachineSettings invalidated on xpc_connection_cancel()

backupd com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid

TimeMachineSettings activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.storagekitd.dm

TimeMachineSettings invalidated on xpc_connection_cancel()

kernel  fs_insert_snapshot_metadata:272: disk1s1 snap_name='com.apple.TimeMachine.2023-11-08-144735.local' snap_xid 7293771 extentref oid 629357 sblock oid 580560

diskarbitrationd    created disk, id = /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/hbimbp/2023-11-08-144735/Macintosh HD - Daten?owner=0.

distnoted   register name: com.apple.TimeMachine.LoggingConfigurationChanged object: kCFNotificationAnyObject token: 700000006 pid: 66406

storagekitd Starting to process: {
    Disk = "<DADisk 0x7fe17050eaf0 [0x7ff856635c30]>{id = /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/hbimbp/2023-11-08-144735/Macintosh HD - Daten?owner=0}";
    Operation = Appear;
}

TimeMachineSettings activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.storagekitd.dm

TimeMachineSettings invalidated on xpc_connection_cancel()

backupd com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
```

What is missing here to do a backup?

Comment: Do you have any other backup devices (you should), and if so, are they working? How is the drive connected: directly, or via a hub?

Comment: @LincD. It's connected to a hub, but it has worked before. It may have happend, that I disconnected the hard drive without proper unmouting, however, MacOS does recognise the partitions (I have two) as regular hard drives, just not the one I wanted to have my time machine on.

Comment: I suggest you start by verifying the backup volume in Disk Utility. That will take a long time. Make sure it's formatted as APFS, not HFS. After that, try connecting it to a built-in port, notwithstanding that it may have worked before off the hub. You should also start a new backup on another external drive, as one backup is not enough even if there are no known issues with it.

Comment: @LincD. Thank you. It works now. I did a `diskUtil verifyVolume ...` and `diskutil repairVolume` (not sure if it would've worked without the `repairVolume`) and now I am able to do a backup. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start by verifying (and repairing, if necessary) the backup volume in Disk Utility. That will take a long time. Make sure it's formatted as APFS, not HFS. After that, try connecting the drive to a built-in port, notwithstanding that it may have worked before off the hub. You should also start a new backup on another external drive, as one backup is not enough even if there are no known issues with it.